# Как найти минимальный по стоимости путь между двумя вершинами в графе?

Tags: алгоритм, графы

Но так чтобы кол-во ребер на этом пути не превышало заданного числа к. Алгоритм форда беллмана

Comment: Найти минимальный путь (используйте A* к примеру), сравнить его длину с заданным числом.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D1%8B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Алгоритм неверен.**

Смотрите. Когда вы получили целевой граф, создайте его копию, но невзвешенную (каждое ребро весом 1).
Затем пройдитесь до ней BFS'ом или DFS'ом, вычислите расстояние от стартовой вершины, до остальных. Удалите все вершины, до которых оно больше К. Тогда у вас останется граф, у которого путь от стартовой вершины до любой другой содержит не более К ребер. Перенесите веса из целевого графа на полученную копию (или создайте вторую копию на основе первой и уже на нее перенесите веса). На новой копии запустите Форда-Беллмана, ответ готов. Если вершины, до которой вам нужно найти путь, в копии не существует, то решения нет.

**UPD Верный алгоритм**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

const int INF = 1e9;

int main()
{
    int n, m, k, s, f;
    cin >> n >> m >> k >> s >> f;
    vector <int> dist(n + 1, INF);
    vector <int> dist_new;
    dist[s] = 0;
    vector < vector<int> > edges(m, vector<int>(3));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
        //это мы заполняем массив ребер, все интересное дальше
        cin >> edges[i][0] >> edges[i][1] >> edges[i][2]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
    {
        dist_new = dist;
        for (auto& edge: edges)
        {
            int start = edge[0];
            int end = edge[1];
            int price = edge[2];
            if (dist[start] + price < dist_new[end])
                dist_new[end] = dist[start] + price;
        }
        swap(dist, dist_new);
    }
    if (dist[f] == INF)
        cout << -1 << endl;
    else
        cout << dist[f] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Итак, я, пожалуй, не буду объяснять как в целом работает алгоритм Форда-Беллмана и как именно доказывается его корректность, вы, наверно, знаете, раз решаете задачи на эту тему. Релаксация ребер в этом алгоритме выполняется `n - 1` раз не просто так. Корректность данного алгоритма доказывается по индукции(что нередко для алгоритмов, использующих динамическое программирование). По индукции `n - 1` получается совершенно естественным образом: т.к. мы хотим найти кратчайший путь, состоящий максимум из `n - 1` вершин, необходимо в каком-то плане "рассмотреть" все вершины, это будет означать `n - 1` релаксаций ребер (не рассматривая стартовую вершину). Но если мы проведем `k` релаксаций, до мы как будто "не дойдем" до вершин, путь к которым занимает больше `k` ребер и поэтому такие пути не будут рассмотрены. Это объяснение на пальцах несколько неточно с целью упрощения, более формально и правильно на [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/ford_bellman).

*Сам код не мой, я решал через матрицу смежности и изменяя классическую реализацию, суть модификации та же. Этот код получается большой и некрасивый, поэтому я прикрепил компактный, красивый и понятный.*

Comment: Первый шаг в общем-то не обязателен, `K` можно подсчитывать и на ходу, без особых проблем.

Comment: Умник, это не проходит сдедующий тест,  где первая строка число вершин,  число ребер,  число к, стартовая и конечная: 4 5 2 1 4
1 2 1
2 3 1
3 4 1
1 3 3
1 4 5

Comment: http://acmp.ru/asp/do/index.asp?main=task&id_course=2&id_section=32&id_topic=53&id_problem=1036

Comment: Возможно надо удалять ребра,  которые приводят к путям длиной больше к, но как определять эти ребра

Comment: Да, мой алгоритм неверен, извиняюсь. Но я почитал еще раз про Форда-Беллмана и есть его альтернативная реализация, с помощью которой должно достаточно легко решаться, но я почему то ловлю Runtime error на 4 тесте. Сейчас попытаюсь исправиться.

Comment: upd: задача решилась, я постараюсь рассказать суть, дополнив этот ответ

Comment: Большое спасибо! Не могли бы вы прикрепить и свою реализацию, хочу лучше понять эту тему